# Where does netbeans configurely store breakpoint information?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Where does netbeans configurely store breakpoint information?
Had an issue of phantom breakpoints. Workaround was to right click in breakpoint list view and 'delete all' to get rid of it.

I want to avoid this in future.
Netbeans 7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is the answer i guess

"Workaround was to right click in breakpoint list view and 'delete all' to get rid of it."